# Ruby on Rails has_many :through Association controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

these are my 3 models :

model for User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :patients, through: :treatments
has_many :treatments 
.
.
.
```

model for patient:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :user, through: :treatments 
has_many :treatments, dependent: :destroy
.
.
.
```

model for treatment:

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :patient
belongs_to :user
validates :patient_id, presence: true
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

And this is my treatment table :

```
  class CreateTreatments < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :treatments do |t|
      t.date :teartment_date
      t.text :remark
      t.float :fee
      t.references :patient, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
   add_index :treatments, [:patient_id, :created_at]
 end
end
```

now i want to define a controller to create a new treatment that belongs to a specific user's patient.

this is my controller :

```
  def new
    @treat = Treatment.new
  end

  def create    

   @userpatient = current_user.treatments.build(treat_params)

    if @userpatient.save
    flash[:success] = "new treatment added"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
   end
end
```

but this is the error that i receive, while i want to create a new treatment :

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in TreatmentsController#create

 unknown attribute 'user_id' for Treatment.
```

and this is the current_user :

```
 def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
   @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
   user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
     if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
     log_in user
     @current_user = user
   end
   end
   end
```

i'm new to rails, the basic idea is i want my user to have treatment that belongs to a specific patient.

Thanks to replies i've over come with this issue by adding a reference column . now i receive no, but it does not save any treatments. i mean the part :

```
if @treat.save
  flash[:success] = "new treatment added"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render 'new'
end
```

it does not save and just render 'new' .

i have 2 questions :

1- how can i code my create controller ?

2- how to retrieve my treatments base on patient.what variable should i define in my patient 'show' method to have its treatments retrieved ?

Comment: You should be having `user_id` in `treatments` table.

Comment: Use a migration to add the user_id as @Pavan wrote in the comment before, you can use a reference there like `add_reference :treatments, :user, index: true`.

Comment: Is the user the patient?

Comment: You need to add a column, that maps the relation between your models. It is a good thing to define an index as well, which speeds up the lookup of the corresponding table entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that `User` `has_many :treatments` and that `Treatment` `belongs_to :user`, both associations are expecting to find a `user_id` column in your `treatments` table. You might want to change your migration to include:

```
t.integer :user_id
```

and then drop your tables (if they have no data yet!) and rerun the migrations. Alternatively, you could create a new migration and simply run that:

```
    add_column :treatments, :user_id, :integer
```

Comment: You might want to add an index, I'd also suggest to use `add_reference`.

Comment: I think the user is a patient - so maybe has_many :patients, foreign_key: "user_id".